# Magento 1 - Patch SUPEE-10415 is not applied

Tags: security, patches, magento-1.9.1.1

I have tried to apply path `SUPEE-10415` to magento 1.9.1.0, but its won't succedeed.

Please find the report below.
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully.

ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

> checking file app/Mage.php checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Review/Detail.php checking
>   file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Report/Tag/Product/Detail.php
>   checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Add.php
>   checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Review/Edit/Form.php
>   checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php Hunk
>    #1 FAILED at 186. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED checking file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php Hunk #1
>   FAILED at 142. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Backend/Filename.php
>   checking file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Helper/Data.php checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Adapter/Soap.php checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config.php checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Wsdl/Config/Base.php checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/String.php checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php Hunk #1 FAILED
>   at 90. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml Hunk #1 FAILED at 456. 1 out of
>   1 hunk FAILED checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml
>   Hunk #1 succeeded at 650 (offset -1 lines). Hunk #2 succeeded at 660
>   (offset -1 lines). checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/Backend/Serialized.php
>   checking file app/code/core/Mage/Log/Helper/Data.php checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Rule/Model/Abstract.php checking file
>   app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Block/Adminhtml/Billing/Agreement/Grid.php
>   checking file app/code/core/Zend/Form/Decorator/Form.php checking file
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml
>   Hunk #1 FAILED at 132. 1 out of 1 hunk FAILED checking file
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/billing/agreement/view/tab/info.phtml
>   checking file
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/content.phtml
>   checking file
>   app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/xmlconnect/edit/tab/design/image_edit.phtml
>   checking file app/locale/en_US/Mage_Adminhtml.csv checking file
>   app/locale/en_US/Mage_Customer.csv checking file
>   js/mage/adminhtml/backup.js checking file
>   lib/Varien/Filter/FormElementName.php

Answer (score 0):

Check the below files at mentioned lines for any custom changes. If you haven't made any intentional changes to the below core files, then get the original contents of these files from Magento Site for your magento version and copy them in the respective files.

`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Controller/Action.php` : line 186
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Model/LayoutUpdate/Validator.php` : line 142
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Validator/Image.php` : line 90
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml` : line 456
`app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/backup/dialogs.phtml` : line 132

At times, formatting issues of the core files ( or manual changes ) might cause these errors. Check for known manual changes before reverting.

Reverting to original will fix the issue.